# How to count cells with multiple criteria values within the cell

Tags: excel

I've got a column showing an outcome (positive/negative), and the other column contains the reasons for that outcome in text format, looking something like this:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bgZnZBGY_0iksANrsixRXRSNz0l9REYmJC29ZmygNjs/edit?usp=sharing

What I want to do is to group the reasons together and find the number of outcomes that contain at least one of those "reasons", as seen in columns G and H.

I've tried using =sum(countifs(C3:C9,{"*Understands responsibility*","*Takes instruction well*","*Looks forward to work*"})) for the first grouping, for example, but it only gives me the count for "Understands responsibility", but not the rest.
Using countif alone repeats the count of the outcome if multiple "reasons" in the groupings are under the outcome. (i.e. there's a double count if "Understands responsibility" and "Looks forward to work" are in the same cell for reasons)

Help would be appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: To me this return 7 in Excel on your data. Which would be the correct answer. All I did what copy paste from your GS and enter the formula. So this is not what you want. The answer needs to be 4, because 4 cells have at least one of these words?

Comment: I believe you have to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter insted of pressing only Enter key after formula edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in H3.. needs to be 'Control-Shift-Enter'ed:

```
=SUM(1*(MMULT(1*(TRANSPOSE(ROW(E3:E5))>0),1*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E3:E5,TRANSPOSE(C3:C9))))>0))
```

This results in a "distinct count" per row. It can take a variable number of responses and reason groups; you can change 'E3:E5' in the 2 spots to point to your other groups.